# Formula for returning value from cell IF other cells has specific text

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to create a pricing spreadsheet for the company I work for.

I am looking for a formula that returns a value from a specific cell based on text in two other cells.

An example is:

```
Sheet1:A1="Clear", Sheet1:B1="Black"
Sheet2:A1="Opacity", A2="Clear", A3="Yellow"
Sheet2:B1="Color", B2="Brown", B3="Black"
Sheet2:C1="Price", C2:1, C3:4
```

Return

```
IF Sheet1:A1="Clear" AND Sheet1:B1="Black", RETURN specific value from Sheet2:C column
```

Any tips or references I can look at to get this figured out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think below will help you to reach to the desired answer.

Add a new A column in sheet 2 (Later you can hide this)

sheet2:A1 -> `=CONCATENATE(B2,",",C2)`    Drag to the End of the table.

sheet1:D1 -> `=CONCATENATE(A1,",",B1)`  (Later you can hide this)

sheet1:C1 -> `=VLOOKUP(D1,Sheet2!$A:$D,4,0)`   (What you expected)

Comment: Thanks for this! Much appreciated! I'll have to take a look at this tomorrow. I'll report back in how I do :)

Comment: @Jordan, was this helpful for you?

Comment: It was! Lead me onto a different track that helped me out! Thanks and I apologize for the delay in my response!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried simple vlookup with the values ? Something like:

```
Vlookup ((sheet1$colA & sheet1colB), sheet2$colC, 1,0)
```

Try this. Will test for more and update.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look with this tomorrow when I'm back in the office. Will do some research on vlookups before then as well